# Amplify: 'No Cognito Federated Identity pool provided' with federation login

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using Amplify's React UI kit, and I'm trying to get my social logins working with Cognito.

At the moment, I'm getting `No Cognito Federated Identity pool provided`

Here's the code for the buttons:

```
<AmplifyAuthenticator federated={{
    googleClientId:
        '*id*',
    facebookAppId: '*id*'
}} usernameAlias="email">
    <AmplifySignUp headerText="Create Account" slot="sign-up"/>
    <AmplifySignIn slot="sign-in">
        <div slot="federated-buttons">
            <AmplifyGoogleButton onClick={() => Auth.federatedSignIn()}/>
            <AmplifyFacebookButton onClick={() => Auth.federatedSignIn()}/>
        </div>
    </AmplifySignIn>
</AmplifyAuthenticator>
```

I've tried making an identity pool, and filling in the authentication providers for Cognito, Google and Facebook and still getting the same error.

For the URI's in both the providers, I've included the domain address as a authorised javascript origin, and for the redirect, I added oauth2/idpresponse to the end of the domain.

This is working within the Amplify hosted UI, just not with my React solution.

On Cognito, my redirect is my domain /token. As I wait for Amplify to set the cookies before redirecting the user.

token.tsx

```
export default function TokenSetter() {
    const router = useRouter();
    useAuthRedirect(() => {
        // We are not using the router here, since the query object will be empty
        // during prerendering if the page is statically optimized.
        // So the router's location would return no search the first time.
        const redirectUriAfterSignIn =
            extractFirst(queryString.parse(window.location.search).to || "") || "/";

        router.replace(redirectUriAfterSignIn);
    });

    return <p>loading..</p>;
}
```

Here's my Amplify.configure()

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        region: process.env.USER_POOL_REGION,
        userPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID,
        userPoolWebClientId: process.env.USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
        IdentityPoolId: process.env.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
        oauth: {
            domain: process.env.IDP_DOMAIN,
            scope: ["email", "openid"],
            // Where users get sent after logging in.
            // This has to be set to be the full URL of the /token page.
            redirectSignIn: process.env.REDIRECT_SIGN_IN,
            // Where users are sent after they sign out.
            redirectSignOut: process.env.REDIRECT_SIGN_OUT,
            responseType: "token",
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Are you federating at the user pool or at the identity pool? In your `Amplify.configure`  call `IdentityPoolId` should be `identityPoolId`

Comment: @AndrewGillis With the error message, I assumed I need to spesifiy an identity pool. I believe I'm federating at the moment with the user pool. I'll fix that typo

Comment: Don't worry the confusion is warranted, amplify made a mess of distinguishing the two. The federate buttons are for directly federating with the identity provider to then exchange for AWS credentials with identity pool. To link directly to cognito user pool federated identty providers is a little more manual. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @AndrewGillis Thank you Andrew, very much appriciate your help with this

Answer (score 2):

In order to call an user pool federated IDP directly from your app you need to pass the provider option to `Auth.federatedSignIn`:

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({
  provider: provider,
})
```

The options are defined in an enum.

```
export enum CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider {
    Cognito = 'COGNITO',
    Google = 'Google',
    Facebook = 'Facebook',
    Amazon = 'LoginWithAmazon',
    Apple = 'SignInWithApple',
}
```

Not exhaustive unfortunately. If you have a custom OIDC or SAML idp you use the provider name or id.

For Facebook the call looks like so:

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({
  provider: 'Facebook',
})
```

Integrated with a button:

```js
const FacebookSignInButton = () => (
  <AmplifyButton
    onClick={()=>Auth.federatedSignIn({provider: 'Facebook'})}>
    Sign in with Facebook
  </AmplifyButton>
)
```

Comment: I'll give that a try now. I'll use <AmplifyButton> instead of what I had before as well

Comment: Seem to be getting `404 page not found` with the url: `*domain*/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F*domain*%2Ftoken&response_type=token&client_id=*client_id*identity_provider=Facebook&scope=email%20openid&state=*state*` sorry for this very bad looking url

Comment: You sure you got your hosted UI domain right? The one your are passing with `process.env.IDP_DOMAIN` should be the hosted ui domain you've set up on your user pool.

Comment: this one? `*name*.auth.eu-west-2.amazoncognito.com`. The website is hosted on a different domain, I'm using that one for IDP_DOMAIN

Comment: Yep that's the one

Comment: Currently getting `https://*domain*/token#access_token=` on a unrecognised page,thinking if I need cognito to redirect me to /token I need to change my cognito redirect from `https://*domain*/token` to `https://*domain*/token/`

Comment: The redirects should be to your application. Also, change the response type to code. Implicit flow should no longer be used.

Comment: The regular create account works fine, it's just the fed buttons. I'm using the amplify react UI. Hosted UI worked fine before. I've changed implicit flow to code so I'll see how that does